# Azure - Access to non-administrator users

Tags: azure

We're using Azure to maintain our development and QA servers.
One of the needs we have now, is to provide our QA members access to update web.config file on the server, which can be achieved via Visual Studio Server's Explorer (with the right configuration). 
The problem is that you need a user with a subscription as a co-administrator within Azure (at least as far as I managed to understand), but obviously we'd like to allow our QA members only to maintain the files, with limited access via Visual Studio.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you give them access via FTP instead?

Comment: That's an option...not very convenient, but an option...

Comment: I noticed the same thing as you working with another dev.  I had granted them access to log into the portal and do all kinds of things to the resources....but they couldn't see the resources from the VS Server Explorer.

Comment: AFAIK, accessing the portal is available only for co-administrators\subscription owners, how did you achieved that?

Comment: The [preview portal](https://portal.azure.com) has RBAC.

Answer (score 0):

Following Brendan advice, I've granted the QA members FTP access. This should do the job for now, until Microsoft will come up with something better :)
Thanks Brendan!

Comment: I've been thinking about this this morning.  What type of changes to the `web.config` are being made?  Is it just app settings / connection strings?

Comment: Yes, mainly for failed scenarios\global configuration tests, but they also need the log file which reside in the root folder of the application for now.